# Rearrange (reorder, sort) array the way you want php

Tags: php

I have an array that results in something like this: a = laranja b = banana c = maçã d = limao

Now I want to reorder it, but there is not something logical, like, d,c,b,a. 
I want to just reorder the way i want. could be a,d,c,b or , c,a,b,d.

I tried sort, multisort, but without sucess.

Are there some advice?

I paste some code  [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6xhYOZ)  to see if its helps

Comment: What exactly did you try? `array_multisort` seems to do what you want. Make sure you read the documentation properly and understand how it works.

Comment: Your code just prints out the array. It's not clear from the question or the code exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I know it is not an intelligent question, but I am trying to reoder but it is not by ASC or DESC and it is not random too. I want do order it the way I want. The data is from a Database. I don't know if I could do this in the sprintf select, but i still could not find how to do it.

Comment: @JGSilva I want that I could read minds but I can't. So tell us what's your mysterious sorting way.`

Comment: Most psychics (mind-readers) can't program, most programmers can't read minds. Good luck finding someone who can do both. 

BTW: (s)he is probably sending you an invoice for writing the code few moths ago.

Comment: @PLB, I found the answer and no one read my mind. Sorry if my question was not clear, but don't forget this: dumb is not one that asks too much, but he who does not know enough to have questions. In fact, I am between both situations, as you can see rsrsrsr. I am just another boy learning PHP. XD

Comment: The same form @GermannArlington : dumb is not one that asks too much, but he who does not know enough to have questions. But I really could not understand why programmers are so I-LL-ONLY-HELP-IF-THE-QUESTION-IS-VERY-DIFFICULT. Sorry if you guys thinks like that. But many Thanks to Fluffeh and his pacience with me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

```
$yourArray;
sort($yourArray);
print_r($yourArray);
// Now alphabetical
```

Also if you write a function to sort the values however you want, use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
    return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>

0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 5
4: 6
```

Edit:

Your foreach statement is kaput.

```
<?php
    function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a == $b) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    $a = array("d"=>"limao", "a"=>"laranja", "b" =>"banana", "c"=>"maçã");
    print_R($a);
    usort($a, "cmp");
    print_R($a);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [d] => limao
    [a] => laranja
    [b] => banana
    [c] => maÃ§Ã£
)
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => laranja
    [2] => limao
    [3] => maÃ§Ã£
)
```

Comment: could you look [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xNaDxd)? Just trying to use this in my case, but can't understand where is the incorrect thing...

Comment: @JGSilva Ignore my bad language settings, but this should show you what is happening :)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to add another entry in the array called something like `sort_order`
which has a numeric weight, and sort by that.

Like:

```
Array (
  Array ( 'name' => 'test', 'sort' => 1 ),
  Array ( 'name' => 'test test', 'sort' => 2 )
);
```